# Why does C2DM/GCM not use SMS as a transport to save battery life?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging, battery

As I understand it, GCM uses [long polling push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) to implement immediate push.

This costs battery dearly, compared with SMS or a technology similar to Blackberry push (presumaby using a specific [GSM MAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Application_Part)) to inform the phone to contact the server for the payload over TCP.

What are the reasons for Google not appearing to pursue a GSM push mechanism to save battery life?

Comment: it piggybacks on the gtalk technology. So why reinvent everything, and what if telephony is not present. And there is cost to send as sms. You cannot make it free

Comment: because sms cost money? (however, apple used to use sms for email push before the long-pulling system was up and running)

Comment: I guess to send millions sms per day will be very expensive. Plus SMPP middleware could be very sensitive to such highloads.

Comment: SMS should be much lower bandwith than GCM, saving the operator airtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know exactly, but may be because, some devices may not contain the SIM card, like some Tablets does not have SIM card facility, so sending SMS, will not be possible on those devices.

So to have a generalized solution for all devices, they might be supporting this mechanism.

Comment: You could always use SMS (or some other GSM push technology) when available, and fall back to long polling otherwise when all you have is some sort of Internet connection.